# How to find all mesh faces illuminated by a SpotLight?

Tags: javascript, three.js, lighting

I have a `THREE.Mesh` consisting of a `THREE.BufferGeometry` with `"position"` and `"normal"` `THREE.BufferAttribute`s.

The mesh is illuminated by a `THREE.SpotLight` (a cone-shaped light source).

Is there a way to find all mesh faces illuminated by the cone? There are no other objects in the scene so I don't need to worry about blocking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### A basic approach

From a very basic perspective, "illuminated by" can also be read as "within or intersecting, and facing the cone."

So first, determine if the face is inside or intersecting the cone. To do this, take all three vertices of the triangle and build a `Vector3` that indicates the direction from the `spotlight.position` to vertex.

```js
// Note: Extracting the vertices of a face will be different
//       depending on if it is indexed or not.
// Assume "vertex1", "vertex2", and "vertex3" are the vertices of the face.

// Convert the vertices into World Coordinates
mesh.localToWorld( vertex1 )
mesh.localToWorld( vertex2 )
mesh.localToWorld( vertex3 )

// Get the spotlight's "look at" direction
const spotLook = new Vector3().subVectors( spotlight.target.position, spotlight.position )

// Make the vertex vectors relative to the spotlight
vertex1.sub( spotlight.position )
vertex2.sub( spotlight.position )
vertex3.sub( spotlight.position )

// Get the angles between the vectors
const angle1 = spotLook.angleTo( vertex1 )
const angle2 = spotLook.angleTo( vertex2 )
const angle3 = spotLook.angleTo( vertex3 )
```

Now, if ANY of these angles is less than the `spotlight.angle` value, then that vertex is inside the cone of the spotlight. If they're all greater than the spotlight's angle, then they're all outside the cone.

Now you need to determine whether the face is angled toward the spotlight. You can do this by normalizing the vectors between the vertices then crossing them.

```js
// These are the original values of the vertices
vertex1.sub( vertex2 )
vertex1.normalize()
vertex3.sub( vertex2 )
vertex3.normalize()
const crossed = new Vector3().crossVectors( vertex3, vertex1 )
```

This gives you the "face normal," or the direction in which the face is facing. Again, use `angleTo` to get the angle against the spotlight's direction. If the angle is greater than `Math.PI/2` (90°), then the face leans *toward* the spotlight. If the angle is *greater than* that value, then the face leans *away* from the spotlight.

If a face passes both criteria--facing *toward* the spotlight, AND at least one vertex is inside the cone--then the face can be considered illuminated.

### Caveats

Of course, this is a basic approach, and provides only basic results.

There may be scenarios where your shape has sections that occlude its own faces (self-shadow).

The actual normals of the face may also reduce its acceptance of light. Even if the face its self is angled *toward* the spotlight, if all the normals are angled *away*, then the face would be within acceptable bounds, but the shader would NOT illuminate the face.

There may also be scenarios where the `penumbra` of your spotlight actually causes a face to NOT be illuminated, even though some or all of it is within your spotlight cone.

These are scenarios you'll need to take into account to arrive at the results you seek.

Comment: Thanks, a basic approach is a great starting point and I'm glad to have it!

Am I correct that there are four cases to handle for a full solution?

1. All vertices contained in cone (fully contained)
2. Some vertices contained in cone (face intersect)
3. No vertices contained in cone (edge or face intersect)
4. No vertices contained in cone (no intersect)

Is it safe to assume that the basic approach fully solves case 1?

Comment: @Nevermore The basic case should solve cases 1, 2, and 4. Case 3 is where a face intersects the cone, but doesn't have any vertices inside the cone. There is probably some trigonometry that can help you find this case, but I'm not sure where to start at the moment.

Comment: That makes sense. I think this approach works well enough for my use-case, it probably wouldn't be worth the extra computation to completely rule out case 3. I've also taken to transforming the cone into the mesh's local space for efficiency which seems to be working well.

Comment: Also, I tried to suggest an edit but the "edit queue" is full. When computing `spotLook`, the spotlight target position is accessed by `spotlight.target.position` rather than `spotlight.target`